# If $f(x)=3x-4$, $f\circ g^{-1}(x)=5x+7$..

Tags: functions

If $f(x)=3x-4$, $f\circ g^{-1}(x)=5x+7$ and $g(x)=5f(x)+7$, find the value of $x$
[image]

[image]

What is the difference between these two solutions. If there are no any differences then why do the answers not match?

Comment: Sideways, handwritten math is pretty hard to read.  Try typing it up with [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Also note that the composition symbol $\circ$ is obtained by typing `\circ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $g(x)=5f(x)+7$ , we get $g^{-1}(x)=f^{-1}(\frac{x-7}{5})$ (Check yourself)

(Without using any other equation)

And from $fog^{-1}(x)=5x+7$, using the value of $g^{-1}(x)$ as obtained above, we get :

$\frac{x-7}{5}=5x+7$ and from there we get $x=-\frac{7}{4}$

(Here's the important part note that for this x, we are allowed to take only $g^{-1}(x)$. Keep this point in mid for later)

Note that we did not use the first equation here. Now when we add the first equation, $f(x)=3x-4$ , you get $g^{-1}(x)=\frac{5x+13}{4}$ and $g(x)=15x-13$ by eliminating $f$ from the two equations and this is where the problem starts. You can see that while trying to solve the above two equations, you can try two methods :

1) Finding $g$ from $g^{-1}$

2) Finding $g^{-1}$ from $g$

If you find $g$ from $g^{-1}$ you will get answer as $\frac{3}{4}$ and here you are allowed to take $g(x)$. For finding $g^{-1}$ from $g$, you will get answer as $x=-\frac{7}{4}$ and here you can only take $g^{-1}(x)$. AND to satisfy everything, you have $g(\frac{3}{4})=-\frac{7}{4}$. So one is answer for $g(x)$ and the other is answer for $g^{-1}(x)$. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Then we can follow both the methods?

Comment: @ Arghya I could not understand clearly, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @user335710 See, $g$ is a function from $R$ to $R$. So, in your mind keep two copies of $R$, one in left one in right and suppose $g$ takes a point from the left to the right. So, $g^{-1}$ takes a value from the right to the left. One answer is for the left, say x. The other answer that we are getting is $g(x)$. We are getting this answer as when we are using$g^{-1}$, we are writing $g^{-1}(x)$. Instead try this, while taking function $g$ write $g(x)$ and while taking $g^{-1}$, write $g^{-1}(y)$. Now you will understand that one answer is $x$ and one answer is $y$.

Comment: @user335710 The reason we are getting this problem is that the domain of $g$ and $g^{-1}$  aren't the same, but you are thinking that $x$ satisfying $g$ and $x$ satisfying $g^{-1}$ as same. Instead think of one as $x$ and one as $y$ and you will understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that either one of the two equations involving $g$ can be used as a definition for $g$.

In the first solution you find $g$ using $f\circ g^{-1}(x)=5x+7$ as a *definition* of $g$, and you interpret $g(x)=5f(x)+7$ as a equation for $x$, not a definition of $g$.

In the second one you instead use $g(x)=5f(x)+7$ as a definition of $g$, then solve $g^{-1}(x)=5x+7$ regarding it as an equation.

Comment: Are both the methods correct then?